# FQL and business hours

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm querying information from a Facebook page for a small business using FQL and I'm trying to parse the business hours.  The numbers I am getting back seem to represent seconds but I'm not sure when the epoch is.  Wednesday and Thursday are the most confusing - open on Thursday is "57600" which would be 16 hours in seconds which would make 4pm Wednesday the epoch, but the closing hours on Wednesday - far past 4- are in the 600,000+ range.

Mon: 8:15am-12pm and 1pm - 5pm Tue:    8am-12pm and 1pm - 5pm Wed: 8am-12pm    and 1pm - 9pm Thur:8am-12pm and 1pm -    5pm Fri:8am-12pm and 1pm - 5pm    Sat:8am-12pm and 1pm - 5pm

```
<hours>
      <mon_1_open>404100</mon_1_open>
      <mon_1_close>417600</mon_1_close>
      <tue_1_open>489600</tue_1_open>
      <tue_1_close>504000</tue_1_close>
      <wed_1_open>576000</wed_1_open>
      <wed_1_close>590400</wed_1_close>
      <thu_1_open>57600</thu_1_open>
      <thu_1_close>72000</thu_1_close>
      <fri_1_open>144000</fri_1_open>
      <fri_1_close>158400</fri_1_close>
      <sat_1_open>230400</sat_1_open>
      <sat_1_close>244800</sat_1_close>
      <sun_1_open>0</sun_1_open>
      <sun_1_close>0</sun_1_close>
      <mon_2_open>421200</mon_2_open>
      <mon_2_close>435600</mon_2_close>
      <tue_2_open>507600</tue_2_open>
      <tue_2_close>522000</tue_2_close>
      <wed_2_open>594000</wed_2_open>
      <wed_2_close>622800</wed_2_close>
      <thu_2_open>75600</thu_2_open>
      <thu_2_close>90000</thu_2_close>
      <fri_2_open>162000</fri_2_open>
      <fri_2_close>176400</fri_2_close>
      <sat_2_open>248400</sat_2_open>
      <sat_2_close>262800</sat_2_close>
      <sun_2_open>0</sun_2_open>
      <sun_2_close>0</sun_2_close>
    </hours>
```

If I change it to simply 8am-5pm Monday to Saturday I get an equally confusing response from FB

```
<hours>
      <mon_1_open>403200</mon_1_open>
      <mon_1_close>435600</mon_1_close>
      <tue_1_open>489600</tue_1_open>
      <tue_1_close>522000</tue_1_close>
      <wed_1_open>576000</wed_1_open>
      <wed_1_close>608400</wed_1_close>
      <thu_1_open>57600</thu_1_open>
      <thu_1_close>90000</thu_1_close>
      <fri_1_open>144000</fri_1_open>
      <fri_1_close>176400</fri_1_close>
      <sat_1_open>230400</sat_1_open>
      <sat_1_close>262800</sat_1_close>
      <sun_1_open>0</sun_1_open>
      <sun_1_close>0</sun_1_close>
      <mon_2_open>0</mon_2_open>
      <mon_2_close>0</mon_2_close>
      <tue_2_open>0</tue_2_open>
      <tue_2_close>0</tue_2_close>
      <wed_2_open>0</wed_2_open>
      <wed_2_close>0</wed_2_close>
      <thu_2_open>0</thu_2_open>
      <thu_2_close>0</thu_2_close>
      <fri_2_open>0</fri_2_open>
      <fri_2_close>0</fri_2_close>
      <sat_2_open>0</sat_2_open>
      <sat_2_close>0</sat_2_close>
      <sun_2_open>0</sun_2_open>
      <sun_2_close>0</sun_2_close>
    </hours>
```

Am I missing some defacto standard time representation?  How would someone go about parsing this as a legitimate time of day?

Comment: If you let me know what language you're using to do the FQL query, I can help you out with parsing the correct time from the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unix epoch is the time `00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970`. Any time you see the term "epoch" used in relation to computer-based time, that's usually what it means.

In UTC, `404100` is `Mon, 05 Jan 1970 16:15:00 GMT`. Or, in the PST timezone, `Mon, 05 Jan 1970 08:15:00 PST`, which is the time you're expecting. Ignore the date; it's irrelevant, anyways.

You can test what I'm describing using this [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

Comment: That seems to check out. I was using epoch as a generic term as it didn't occur to me that they'd represent times using the unix epoc and take day of the week into consideration (Jan 1 was a Thursday in 1970). D'oh, I should have thought. Thank you